# Excel - Returning only counts if two cells match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below test table in Excel.  I am looking to be able to use the `COUNTIFS` formula (or another if able to) where it would only return rows if cells **DATE1** and **DATE2** match.

I cannot enter the dates directly into the formula as the dates can be any range up to 3 years ago.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Excel Test Table]

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[DATE1] = Table1[DATE2]))
```

Blanks can be ignored like this, but using the whole column is much slower:

```
=SUMPRODUCT( (A:A = B:B) * (A:A <> "") )
```

Comment: was on the point to post e.x.a.c.t.l.y the same answer, not one single different character :)

Comment: I attempted this and keep getting an error when trying to enter the formula.  It states Array1 is invalid.  I have replaced the Table1 with the table to reference.  I modified it to "=SUMPRODUCT(--(MASTER!$E:$E = MASTER!$H:$H))" but now it returns even the rows that have no information.

Comment: It seems to work if I have specific cell references (i.e. E1:E6) but not a defined name or column (TABLE1!$C:$C).

Comment: @MichaelSiepel it uses [structured references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) because of the Excel Table in the sample screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're wanting to count but:

```
=if(A1=C1,do something, do something else)
```